# How to automatically respond to a request in Burp?

Tags: burp

I am using Burp as a reverse proxy (a.k.a. "invisible proxying" in the app). For requests that match a specific rule, I need to not forward them to the real server but respond with a predefined response (in form of headers + body or from file). Similarly to AutoResponder feature in Fiddler. I did not find the way to do it in Burp. Is there such a functionality, and if so, how to activate it?

Comment: I don't see such an option in Burp but you can try Proxy -> Options -> Match and Replace and change the response from server. You can change both response headers and response body.

Comment: I see... but I don't need to change, I just want to skip calling the server at all.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, they don't have that option. Burp Suite confirmed in the [link](https://forum.portswigger.net/thread/burp-pro-programmatically-create-responses-132865f6).
In the other hand, you can use intercept matching some conditions of the traffic you want, then manually change it.
Since you just want to 'skip calling the server', you can use match and replace in order to redirect traffic to your local host.